# VScode python unittest test discover issue

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, python-unittest

I can run all my tests from cmd

```
(venv) PS D:\13_projects\xxx> python -m unittest discover -s .\tests\ -p 'test*.py' -b
...................................
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 35 tests in 0.426s

OK
```

but no tests are discovered by the VScode (the same test configuration settings and virtual environment is used)

```
    "python.testing.unittestArgs": [
        "-v",
        "-s",
        "./tests",
        "-p",
        "test*.py"
    ],
```

I'm sure it worked in past. As far as I realize I didn't change any settings.

This is my version of VScode

[image]

**Do you have any hints what to check?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of things to try:

1. Go through the process of configuring the tests in VSCode. Type ctrl+shift+p, then search "Python: Configure Tests".
   [image: Configure Tests]
2. See what the test output in VSCode shows when discovering the tests.
   [image: Test Log]
3. Ensure `__init__.py` files are included in your project folders, and possibly even the tests folder (even though testing doesn't usually require this). I've noticed strange behavior here before but don't recall exactly what the fix was.

Comment: I didn't know that I can change the content of the Output tab! I see there all my tests are actually found. Why I didn't see them on the left tree view - they are in the Python section was collapsed in the bottom... Stupid...  thanks a lot! :)